# How can I slow down readings I get from a QR Scanner?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reader

this is my first post.
greetings to readers.

So Im fairly new to coding, and ive got this code implemented onto my frontend, a succesful scan sends a GET request to my python API to fetch data from database.. but this script scans qr code few times a second (not only that but it submits it too).

So my question is how could I slow it down a bit, lets say a timeout for 2 seconds after a succesful scan?

```
 function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    // Handle on success condition with the decoded text or result.
    console.log(`Scan result: ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
    $('#search').val(decodedText);
    $('#frm').submit();
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
});
```

edit: I havent said I didnt write this and I have no idea how to do timeouts in Typescript or Javascript and not even where.

Im thanking you for your time :)

Comment: By lowering `fps`?

Comment: You can save last `onScanSuccess` full execution time and if it's longer than threshold, send once more

Comment: Hi @DennisKatalinic welcome to SO, coming from a backend background will feel a bit daunting at first but you got this, how about trying to set a timeout for the onScanSuccess function like `setTimeout(() => {your function}, 5000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken directly from the [html5QrcodeScanner](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/tree/master/examples/html5)  example. On success, it will update the result, and if there's no new result scanned, it wont update the result

```
var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
var lastResult, countResults = 0;

function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
        ++countResults;
        lastResult = decodedText;
        // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
        console.log(`Scan result ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
    }
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

but this wont stop your device from scanning, it just won't update the result as from my understanding of your question that would be sufficient, but if you want to stop the camera/ scanning process altogether after successful scan, you can go into a lil bit advanced part of the library

```
import {Html5Qrcode} from "html5-qrcode"

const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode("reader");

html5QrCode.stop().then((ignore) => {
  // QR Code scanning is stopped.
}).catch((err) => {
  // Stop failed, handle it.
});
```

by doing this also means that you need to implement the whole process from Pro Mode, you can refer [here](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode#pro-mode---if-you-want-to-implement-your-own-user-interface) for pro mode

Comment: this answered my question, it does what its supposed to do. 
I actualy need for it to scan and not stop it.. but just not send the same request over and over.. thank you very much sir :)

Comment: @DennisKatalinic most welcome, please do accept it as answer if it helps you.